# How to pass function groups as props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I use this simple React component only for example.

I would like to access this.setState() inside the functions 'working' and 'group.notWorking'.

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },

  working: function() {
    this.setState({ test: true });  //this is myComponent
  },

  group: {
    notWorking: function() {
      console.log(this); //this is window
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <ChildComponent working={this.working} group={this.group}/>
        </div>
    );
  },
});
```

My question is how do you pass functions grouped in an object, or is there any best practice, to avoid passing all the functions one by one to children components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a bound version of it.

```
<ChildComponent working={this.working} group={this.group.notWorking.bind(this)}/>
```

If you want to pass the whole group you need to make it a function which returns an object and bind it:

```
group: function() {
    return {
        notWorking: function() {
          console.log(this);
        }.bind(this)
    };
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind