# Is there a way to pass a group of props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

The way I actually use works well but my props keep growing and I wondering if I can group them into one single state and pass it to the child, this is my code:

```
    <Panel
      uniqueIDs={uniqueIDs}
      userID={userID}
      loading={loading}
      premium={premium}
      percent={percent}
      total={total}
      until={until}
      user={user}
      done={done}
    />
```

After the render I define those variable like so :

> let { loading, empty, total, uniqueIDs, slice, percent, until, ok,
>   user, premium, data, keys, done, userID } = this.state;

Can i just send `this.state` variable? I made a little bit of research I didn't find any solution to my issue, I know I can use third-party libraries to manage state but I am trying to keep it simple.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452684/how-to-pass-function-groups-as-props-in-react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass function groups as props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452684/how-to-pass-function-groups-as-props-in-react)

Comment: Put props into an object and pass the object as a prop to component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you definitely could just pass your entire state-variable into your child-component as multiple properties

```
<Child {...this.state}/>
```

This would be perfectly acceptable.

If your state is `{id: 1, name: 2}`

You would still be able to access the props in your child-component as

```
props.id or this.props.id
props.name or this.props.name
```

As a note you should be cognizant of component re-rendering. If you make many updates to the state in your parent-component this will also cause your Child component to re-render a lot as well, which could have performance issues.

To workaround this, make sure to employ methods like `componentDidUpdate()` for class-components and `react-hooks` for functional components. These can help control the flow of re-rendering.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, thanks so much! I knew I had to use spread operator. On childs I can access them with this.props tho

Comment: You're welcome! I updated my answer to give you a quick-note about component re-rendering because I think that is something you might be interested in.

Comment: Much appreciated! I am looking forward implementing hooks

Comment: This also seems to work if you wouldn't want to pass all state props to the child component: <Panel {...{uniqueIDs, userID}} />

Answer (score 5):

you can make an object for the props you are sending and can use spread operator

```
  let props = {
        uniqueIDs : uniqueIDs,
        userID:userID,
        loading:loading,
        premium:premium
          }
<Panel {...props} />
```

In panel component you can use this.props.uniqueIDs ans so on.

Comment: still a pain to group all props and remember everything! but it works, thanks for the input.